No sound after updating to Ubuntu 24.04
I updated my PC to Ubuntu 24.04 and I now don't have sound on my computer (headphones work). I'm using the  Nvidia-driver-535 and I have a RTX 4070  graphic card. I had sound with 23.10 but not with 24.04.
